# AS3/AIR - Desktop application alerts (?)

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air, alert

Is it possible to generate alerts in AS3 for Adobe Air desktop applications running in Win OS?

Developing in Flash CS5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the mx.controls.Alert class into your application, and then call the static show() method in ActionScript to display an Alert control. You cannot create an Alert control in MXML.

The Alert control closes when you select a button in the control, or press the Escape key.

More info here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html

There is no built in way to get native alerts in AIR with Flash, but here's a workaround:
http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2012/03/simple-way-to-get-native-alerts-with-adobe-air/

Comment: Sorry. I didn't say that I'm coding in Flash (CS5). Anyway, thank you.

Comment: It was tested by me and it works perfectly ;)
If it answers your question, please accept it and upvote so that other's who has a similar problem can find it.